# Zoom_changed - Center

Tags: javascript

I want to add zoom_changed AddListner to my map but it is not working .Any one help me to resolve this Thanks in Advance.My code is

```
 GEvent.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
    alert("You before Zoomed the map.");
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(17.971599, 77.594563), 10);
    alert("You After Zoomed the map.");
 }
```

it works fine for click instead of zoom_changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the google maps api v2, you can not use zoom_changed instead try zoomend.

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "zoomend", function() {
  alert("You before Zoomed the map.");
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(17.971599, 77.594563), 10);
  alert("You After Zoomed the map.");
}
```